# How to update sharded collection from dataframe using MongoSpark?

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I'm using MongoSpark scala connector to load a collection, process it in spark and I want to update the same collection with the result.

I have a dataframe with the structure:

```
root
 |-- _id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- oid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- provider: string (nullable = true)
 |-- solution: string (nullable = true)
```

_id and provider are the sharded keys in mongo but when I run the update with:

```
MongoSpark   
  .write(df_update)
  .option("uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1/")
  .option("database", "test")
  .option("collection", "solutions")
  .option("replaceDocument", "false")
  .mode("append").save()
```

I get:

```
Write errors: [BulkWriteError{index=0, code=61, message='upsert { q: { _id: ObjectId('57ebd3d227e9c712d83737c9') }, u: { $set: { provider: "someProvider", solution: "blahblahblah" } }, upsert: true } does not contain shard key for pattern { provider: 1.0 }', details={ }}]
```

It looks like mongospark is not using `provider` as part of the query and because of that I get the shard stuff error...

Is there a way to force mongospark to use X columns to query and Y columns to update?

I'm using mongo 3.4.7 and spark 2.2.0

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the Mongo Spark 2.2 version as well?

Comment: yes I am. thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug opened at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SPARK-147 where they said that it will be solved in the SparkMongo version 2.3.0.

It seems that there is no current option for this working.